# iOS - Revoking a submitted binary

Tags: ios, app-store

How to revoke a submitted binary ?

I uploaded a version of my app to the appstore that hasn't been verified yet.
Except that I already want to replace it.

Before, it was enough to proceed as on this [link](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808568-iOS-Revoking-a-Submitted-Binary).

But now I no longer have access to this feature.

How to do ?

Comment: Your question is a kind of confusing, but if u want to upload same version number build follow the below.
You can upload a new build with the same version, but different build number. so that u can choose another build.

Comment: Nothing has changed. Still unable to submit a new build.